# Redirect with ci flash message Connot modify header information error occue

Tags: codeigniter

I'm trying to redirect after executing some code with flash message then apache hang and sent error

> Connot modify header information - headers already sent

```
   public function convert_to_invoice($id)
{
    if (!has_permission('invoices', '', 'create')) {
        access_denied('invoices');
    }
    if (!$id) {
        die('No estimate found');
    }
    $draft_invoice = false;
    if ($this->input->get('save_as_draft')) {
        $draft_invoice = true;
    }
    $invoiceid = $this->estimates_model->convert_to_invoice($id, false, $draft_invoice);
    if ($invoiceid) {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('message-success','estimate_convert_to_invoice_successfully');
            redirect('invoices/list_invoices/' . $invoiceid); 
    } else {
        if ($this->session->has_userdata('estimate_pipeline') && $this->session->userdata('estimate_pipeline') == 'true') {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('estimateid', $id);
        }
        if ($this->set_estimate_pipeline_autoload($id)) {
            redirect($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
        } else {
            redirect(admin_url('estimates/list_estimates/' . $id));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As `redirect` uses headers to perform its task *nothing* can be outputted before it is called. I don't see anything that would cause output except:

```
if (!has_permission('invoices', '', 'create')) {
        access_denied('invoices'); // exits?
    }
    if (!$id) {
        die('No estimate found');
    }
```

However both seem to exit so the `redirect` stage shouldn't be reached.

I would suggest removing the redirects temporarily, running the script, and seeing what is outputting. You can then remove/silence those offending pieces of code and re-institute the redirects. It might be as simple as an error outputting.